# On orbiting electrons losing energy in radiation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, acceleration, atomic-physics, orbitals

I know questions about this have been asked before, but I want to know something specific I haven't seen in the answers for those.

Apparently, an *accelerating* charged particle loses energy, due to emitting radiation. I initially thought of the electromagnetic radiation emitted by a charge moving with a uniform velocity. As far as I know, it shouldn't *lose* energy as long as the electromagnetic field doesn't actually do any work on any body.

1. Is that true? And if so,
2. Is the case of a particle accelerating different from this only because of something called bremsstrahlung radiation (a term I came across in the old answers)? If so, how does it cause the situation to be different for an accelerating particle as opposed to a uniformly moving one?

Comment: There are plenty of answers to your question here. The long and short is: electrons don't orbit the nucleus, that's the obsolete Bohr model. In QM there's no orbiting and no consequent bremsstrahlung. The electron doesn't lose energy.

Comment: Okay, then in the case of a moving charge, is Bremsstrahlung radiation only observed for accelerating particles? If so, this energy loss wouldn't be observed for charges in uniform motion, right?

Comment: Yes.  Radiation is emitted by *accelerating* charges only.  For a charge in uniform motion go to a frame where it is a rest - an equivalent frame according to relativity - and in that frame .. well... it is at rest so as in the static case will not emit.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung